# Regularized Generalized Linear Models with an incidence as response in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, proportion, glmnet, regularization

I'm struggling to find a regularized regression model with a percentage as response variable. I've already seen the glmnet package in R and it seems that there is not way to handle a proportion as response variable on this kind of models.

How can I do a lasso regularization for a glm with Beta distributed response in R?

Comment: The documentation for `glmnet` is great.  Its manual page clearly states it handles binomial, Poisson, and multinomial responses, all of which are applicable to the kinds of data that produce proportions.  It also handles weights and offsets.  What more do you want?

Comment: @whuber thanks for your prompt response. I agree, the documentation for  `glmnet` is great. At first I though about the use of beta regression, but you are right, I'll consider first the binomial model.